# only root can send out mail by postfix

Tags: postfix

I have postfix installed and running. The problem is only root can send email. other users failed to do. Here is the log for user www-data which is a web server application. (the same error for other users)

```
postfix/smtp[32003]: 513765FEB9: to=<xxxx@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:11125, delay=2.1, delays=0.07/0/1.7/0.32, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 550-Verification failed for <www-data@localhost.localdomain> 550-Unrouteable address 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

here is the /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relayhost = [127.0.0.1]:11125
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/lizard_password
smtp_sasl_security_options =    
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.1]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
inet_protocols = ipv4
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
```

and here is the section that I added to the /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf:

```
[smtp-tls-wrapper]
accept = 11125
client = yes
connect = smtp.mydomain.com:465
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
550-Verification failed for <www-data@localhost.localdomain> 550-Unrouteable address 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Gmail is rejecting the message because the sender address is not routable (i.e. `localhost.localdomain` doesn't exist in DNS). You need to specify a valid From address when sending your mail.

It's probably not related to your problem, but you shouldn't be using stunnel -- Postfix can do SSL by itself.

Comment: Then, how come root can send email to the same email address at gmail. Thanks for pointing that postfix can handle SSL by itself. I will check that as well

Comment: Ok, I changed the domain name to somthing valid and every thing is working fine now. Thanks for the hint. Regarding using stunnel, please check this link out http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_smtps.

Comment: @Arash Gmail supports StartTLS on ports 25 (without authentication) and 587 (with authentication).

Comment: I know that. But I need to use another host as my relay host than gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Not a postfix expert, but I'm going to guess it has something to do with `reject_unauth_destination`

From the [manual](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination):

```
reject_unauth_destination
    Reject the request unless one of the following is true:

        Postfix is mail forwarder: the resolved RCPT TO domain matches $relay_domains or a subdomain thereof, and contains no
sender-specified routing (user@elsewhere@domain),
        Postfix is the final destination: the resolved RCPT TO domain matches $mydestination, $inet_interfaces, $proxy_interfaces,
$virtual_alias_domains, or $virtual_mailbox_domains, and contains no
sender-specified routing (user@elsewhere@domain).
```

Comment: removed `reject_unauth_destination`, but did not work

Comment: @Arash: **Never** remove `reject_unauth_destination`. `permit_mynetworks` and `permit_sasl_authenticated` should permit you to send emails if everything else is in place. *How exactly* are you trying to send the email?

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I did it only for testing purpose. I am sending email using `sendmail` like `sendmail xxxx@gmail.com`